# Lis properties of CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi I'm trying to list all of methods and properties of CanvasRenderingContext2D object. I successeed in listing methods however I get strange results when I try to list properties. All I get is ana array of the same property repeated multiple times. Anyone can help me with that?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var methods = [];
        for (var m in ctx) {
            if (typeof ctx[m] == "function") {
                methods.push(m);
                methods.join(',');
            }
        }
        var methodsContainer = document.querySelector('#methods');
        for(var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            var opt = methods[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            methodsContainer.appendChild(el);
        }
  var properties = [];
        for (var key in ctx) {
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ctx)) {
                properties.push(m);
                properties.join(',');
            }
        }

        var propertiesContainer = document.querySelector('#properties');
        for(var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            var opt = properties[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            propertiesContainer.appendChild(el);
        }
```

```html
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 
  
  <h5>Methods</h5>
  <select id="methods">

  </select>
  <br/>
  <h5>Properties</h5>
  <select id="properties">

  </select>
```

Comment: You are always pushing the last method got. (`properties.push(m)`). Also, methods are properties, you'll get it twice if you don't check again if this is a method or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line (after declaring the properties variable):

```
for(var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
```

You're for looping the amount of times the method has values, when you should be looping properties

This line also:

```
for (var key in ctx) {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ctx)) {
            properties.push(m);
            properties.join(',');
        }
    }
```

You're pushing the m variable, when maybe you're intending to push 'key'

Comment: Oh yes, that was a silly typo...however changing it didn't solve the problem:(

Comment: What about this line: properties.push(m);
Where is m declared, should it be key?

Comment: Yep that was it:) simple mistake while copying code. Thanks!